# What is the limit of this sequence as n->infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the following sequence $n^{\ln(n)/n}$ as $n\to\infty$? Please answer without using L'Hopital

Comment: Try to write this with an exponential.

Comment: Aww man, I didn't realize I was going to have to do *homework*.

Comment: @Kalpesh Krishna: [are you just going over all the questions in your homework, without showing any work?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381312/find-limit-of-the-following-sequence)

Comment: Just the two questions. I'll remember to show my work the next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n^{\log(n)/n} = e^{(\log(n))^2/n}$$
Since 
$${(\log(n))^2\over n} \to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$, the limit you seek is $1$.

One question: do you accept the fact that for any $\alpha > 0$,
$${\log(n)\over n^\alpha}\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I do know this fact. Haven't seen a formal proof of it

Comment: Prove it from the fact that $\frac{x^n}{e^x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ which is proved by noting that $e^x>\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Answer (score 1):

Tage the log

$\ln(n^\frac{\ln(n)}{n}) = \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\ln(n) =\frac{\ln^2(n)}{n}$

This will clearly converge to $0$. One way to see it is to make $n = e^t$ and take the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{t^2}{e^t}=0$.

Since the log of the original limit converges to $0$ the original limit converges to $e^0=1$

Comment: n is a natural number

Comment: so? if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)= c$ then by definition for any sequence $a_n\rightarrow a$ $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(a_n)=c$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=n^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$. Then 
$$\ln a_n = \frac{(\ln n)^2}{n}.$$
Now compute this limit (compare polynomial function with logarithmic)